# Unable to click on a box in Selenium Webdriver using Python

Tags: python, html, selenium

I want to click on the box which has 24h as text while testing in Selenium Webdriver using Python but unable to do so.
Python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time

service = Service('/Users/XYZ/Desktop/Selenium/chromedriver.exe')
service.start()
driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url)
driver.get('example.com')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element_by_name("ctl00$BodyContent$Username").send_keys("id")
driver.find_element_by_name("ctl00$BodyContent$Password").send_keys("pwd")
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_BodyContent_LoginButton").click()

driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='75%'")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 225);")

time.sleep(3)## lets say 3 seconds
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='highcharts-114']/svg/g[19]/text").click()
driver.save_screenshot("screenshot.png")
```

HTML Code:

```
<g zIndex="7" states="[object Object]" style="cursor:default;text-align:center;" transform="translate(164,61)"><rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="url(#highcharts-114)" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="27" height="18" stroke-width="1" stroke="#cccccc"></rect><text x="2.1875" y="14" style="font-family:&quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;color:#4d4d4d;fill:#4d4d4d;" zIndex="1"><tspan x="2.1875">24h</tspan></text></g>

<rect rx="0" ry="0" fill="url(#highcharts-114)" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="27" height="18" stroke-width="1" stroke="#cccccc"></rect>

<text x="2.1875" y="14" style="font-family:&quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;color:#4d4d4d;fill:#4d4d4d;" zIndex="1">
<tspan x="2.1875">24h</tspan>
</text>
```

Error Message:

`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='highcharts-114']/svg/g[19]/text"}`
[Box HTML code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSUMZ.jpg)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you, it is usually helpful to include what you have previously attempted, as well as as a detailed explanation of the issue you are attempting to solve. I would recommend reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which offers several tips to this end.

As for right now, I think you should add a complete code example to the question, as it is likely this issue is outside of what you've included so far.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide full code.A blind guess is that probably your page doesnt load in time so element doesnt exist.There are two ways :
The bad :

```
time.sleep(3)## lets say 3 seconds
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='highcharts-114']/svg/g[19]/text").click()
```

and the wait method provided by selenium(recomended).

Comment: I updated my above code with your suggestion, kindly find the new code above. I still get this error

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='highcharts-114']/svg/g[19]/text"}

Comment: then check if this element is in another frame ,cause you need to switch frames if this elemnt belongs to another frame.

Comment: I did check but the element doesn't belong to any other frame. Also I tried clicking the element using "driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '24h')]").click()" and it works for the first element it finds but if I want to click other elements at the bottom of the page it throws an error saying "selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='highcharts-48']/svg/g[19]/text/tspan"}
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.87)"

Answer (score 0):

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
inputBox = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='highcharts-114']//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='g'][19]//*[name()='text']")))
inputBox.click()
```

Note: please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: I tried your solution but the browser window stays still and the box never gets clicked.